# Proving Table of Integral Integral (Trigonometric Substitution)

Tags: integration

I need help with the proof of the table of integral that:
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + u^2}}{u} du = \sqrt{a^2 + u^2} + a \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + u^2} - a}{u}\right| + c$$

Must solve using trigonometric substitution.

I understand that you have to use $a^2\tan(\theta)$ as a substitution for $u$.

Comment: Is this what you meant? If not, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to change it yourself.

Comment: take the derivation of the right side and compare it with the left?

Comment: Why must you use trig substitution?  Of course, to prove something in the integral table, you merely have to differentiate the right hand side and verify that it is the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=a \tan x \tag{1}$  Then:- $u^2=a^2\tan^2 x  \implies 2u \cdot du= 2a^2\tan x \cdot \sec^2x \cdot dx $

The integral reduces to :- $$ a\int \sec^2x \csc x \cdot dx $$
$$ =  a\int (\tan^2x +1) \csc x \cdot dx = a\left(\int \sec x \tan x \cdot dx + \int \csc x \cdot dx \right)\\
= a\left(\sec x  - \ln(\cot x + \csc x)\right) + C $$Note that from $(1)$ we have $\sec x = \frac{\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}{a}$  and $\csc x= \frac{\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}{u}$ and $\cot x = \frac{a}{u} $

Thus , by undoing substitution , we get  $$\boxed{ I= \sqrt{a^2+u^2} + a\cdot \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}-a}{u}\right| + C}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help!